# Teensy USB in VirtualBox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, teensy

yesterday i had a problem with my teensy usb in virtualbox getting random keystroke changes, however i fixed it and it works perfectly fine now (i hope, tested it 10 times). Heres the post if u are interested :)
[VirtualBox Keystroke gets random changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595073/virtualbox-keystroke-gets-random-changes/34606502#34606502)

However ive got a another little problem now -.- it only works if i manually bind my teensy as usb to the virtualbox. But atm i have to do that every time i connect my teensy to the pc or after reboot of the vm. i tried doing it with a filter which sadly didnt work, it works for my usb camera and usb stick tho. does anybody got some advice for me? :)

- host os: win8.1 pro
- guest os: win7 professional
- usb device i want to permanently connect to the virtualbox: Van Ooijen Technische Informatica Teensy Keyboard/Mouse/Joystick[0104]

greets

Comment: so i tested a bit more and the filter rules are working perfectly fine with every other usb device i have like stick, camera, keyboard, mouse, external harddrive, ... but not with my teensy stick build in my mouse

Answer (score 0):

ok problem solved, i deleted the 'produkt name' and 'manufacturer' and set the remote acces value to 'both' in the filter rules for the teensy